# Are standalone statements conventionally considered to imply truth?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

From what I understand, the statement $\exists x(p(x) \vee q(x))$ in the English language sounds something like this: "There exists $x$ such that $p(x)$ or $q(x)$". But this sounds like an incomplete claim; "There exists $x$ such that $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ *what*? Are true? Are false?

Comment: I often think *"...holds."* at the end of such a sentence. Such statements are conventionally considered to imply truth.

Comment: @Servaes Meaning "is true"? So the statement $\exists x(p(x) \vee q(x))$ claims "there is an $x$ for which at least one of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is true?

Comment: There's a reason the subject is often called _predicate_ logic. Here $p$ and $q$ are _predicates_. The idea being that "p(x)" _says_ something about $x$. (Or is notation for or an abstraction of the notion of saying something.) Maybe $p(x)$ is $x>2$. Then "there exists $x$ such that $p(x)$" is just the same as "there exists $x$ such that $x>2$". If yyou read that you wouldn't ask "$x>2$ _what_?"

Comment: Remember that $p$ and $q$ are predicates, not nouns or function symbols. They're placeholders for things that become sentences when you plug in a noun, like "$x$ runs for public office" or "$x$ is green and purple".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well you wouldn't ask $x>2$ what because it's clear from the context, but technically you are asking if there exists an $x_0$ such that when you plug it into $x>2$, the proposition $x_0>2$ is true, right?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Many such statements are read aloud as sentences having verbs, e.g. *"x>2"* is read as *"$x$ is greater than two"*, often yielding a sentence that makes sense. But there are also many statements that do not have such a colloquial interpretation, e.g. the statement in the question. Adding *"... is true."* or *"... holds"* to the end of such a sentence makes the meaning clearer, imho, which is why I often do so.

Comment: @Servaes Yes. English sentences have verbs. Predicates. And $p$ _deniotes_ a predicate. Or is a predicate, depending on what level we're talking about...

Comment: @Ovi You guys need to read Lewis Carroll. No, I'm not saying $x>2$ is true. I'm asking whether "$x>2$ is true" is true. Wait, no that's wrong, technically I'm asking whether "'$x>2$ is true' is true" is true. No, I see you point, that's not what I mean, technically I mean to ask whether [[[[$x>2$ is true] is true] is true] is true] is true. NO! "technically" when I say $x>2$ what I mean is $x>2$.

Comment: The statement in the question is only grammatically correct if $p$ and $q$ are predicates.  So $p(x) = \text{x is big}$ or $p(x) = \text{x is happy}$ would make the statement grammatically correct.  $p(x) = x+1$ is a function but not a predicate, so it would be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich When I see a theorem in a math book, such as "If a polynomial $p(x)$ is of degree $n$, then then $p(x)$ has $n$ roots" I think it's meant to be taken as true; meaning, the author is telling us that we will never find a case where the degree $\not =$ the number of roots. If the author weren't claiming that the theorem is true, it wouldn't be of any value, would it? I don't see why we are forced to go down to $[[[x>2$ is true] is true] is true]. Why can't we just stop at  $(x>2)$ is true?

Comment: @Ovi You seem to be missing the point. Why can't we just stop at $x>2$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But what do you think about the theorem example in the above comment? If the statement "a polynomial is of degree $5 \implies$ it has $5$ roots" wasn't implied to be true (at least when stated in a math book) it would carry no information, wouldn't it? Couldn't I also just make up a theorem and put it in a math book, because I don't have to claim it's true?

Comment: @Ovi Cointinually missing the point. Of course when a person states something he's saying that that something is true. That's precisely why we _don't_ need to add "is true" to that statement...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok I think I understand, saying $p \vee q$ is just like saying $2+3$, it's just an expression. We can evaluate it if we want, but as it stands it is just an $expression$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you please take a look at this related question which is a follow up on out discussion?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842900/compound-propositions-as-assertions?noredirect=1#comment3769397_1842900

Comment: See [Assertion](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/assertion/): "An assertion is a speech act in which something is claimed to hold". Thus $\exists x \ p(x)$ assert that there are some $p$'s and it is not "incomplete" at all. There is nothing strange in the natural language assertions: "There are cows".

Comment: The addition of "... it is true" is redundant; in natural language we do not usually assert: "it is true that there are cows".

Comment: See [The Deflationary Theory of Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/): "According to the deflationary theory of truth, to assert that a statement is true is just to assert the statement itself. For example, to say that ‘snow is white’ is true, or that it is true that snow is white, is equivalent to saying simply that snow is white".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the link and for your help on all my questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical formulae like this are always meant to be true, and if what they express is false, so is the formula.
That is, the formula you gave essentially says "It is true that there is an x which is p or q", but since the "It is true that..."-part is already part of the semantics of logical formulae anyway, you wouldn't explicitly spell out this when translating predicate logic into natural language - just like in natural language you don't say either "It is true that the sun shines" but simply "The sun shines."

The reason why "... such that p(x) or q(x)" sounds incomplete may also be due to "p(x)" and "q(x)" not actually being full sentences with a verb etc. as we would expect but just abbreviations; if we substituted "p" and "q" for e.g. to "dog" and "hungry" (and the choice of variable and constant names is irrelevant to the semantics of the formula, as long as we stick to a unique interpretation of them), we could translate the formula into "There exists an x such that x is a dog and x his hungry", which doesn't sound incomplete at all.
So the reason why the formula may sound like an incomplete term to you probably is due to the poor level of translation into natrual language sentences (wording it as "such that p(x)", which isn't a "complete" sentence in sense of lacking a verb etc., instead of wording it e.g. "such that x is p"), rather than the formula itself being incomplete.

The default assumption is always that what the formula expresses is true, and if this is not the case, so is the formula.