# Compound propositions as assertions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

According to comments on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812549/are-standalone-statements-conventionally-considered-to-imply-truth), compound propositions are not assertions; i.e. the statement "$p \vee q$" does not mean "$p$ (is true) or $q$ (is true)", and it does not mean "$(p$ or $q)$ is true".From my understanding, "$p \vee q$" is just an un-evaluated expression, just like $2+3$.

However, my book says

> The statement $p \implies q$ is called a conditional statement because $p \implies q$ asserts that $q$ is true on the condition that $p$ holds

which seems to say that we can interpret "$p \implies q$" as "$p$ (is true) $\implies q$ (is true)". This appears to directly contradict the comments in the other question, especially since we can write a conditional statement as a disjunction. Indeed, if we assume that "$p \vee q$" means "$p$ (is true) or $q$ (is true)", the truth tables match. If we assume  "$p \vee q$" means "$p$ (is false) or $q$ (is false)" instead, the truth table does not match with $p \vee q$; "$p$ (is false) or $q$ (is true)" (or the other way around) doesn't match either.

So my question is:

Is there a contradiction between the comments on my previous question and the book?

If anyone is wondering, my book is "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications" $6^{th}$ edition by Kenneth H. Rosen.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "write a conditional statement as a disjunction"?

Comment: @janezdu I mean that $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $~p \vee q$. My point was that if we assume an assertion of truth only in the case of conditional statements then there wouldn't be a conflict between the book and my other question, but since both refer to disjunctions there appears to be one

Comment: Those two aren't equivalent; for example, when both $p, q$ are false, $p \implies q$ evaluates to true while $p \vee q$ is false.

Comment: @janezdu oops i guess my negation symbol didn't register, i meant to write "not $p \vee q$"

Comment: Why do you think that compound propositions are not *assertions* ? See Rosen, page 33: "To encode a Sudoku puzzle, let $p(i, j, n)$ denote the proposition that is true when the number $n$ is in the cell in the $i$th row and $j$ th column. There are $9 × 9 × 9 = 729$ such propositions [...]. Given a particular Sudoku puzzle, we begin by encoding each of the given values. Then, we construct *compound propositions that assert* that every row contains every number, every
column contains every number [...]  1/2

Comment: "... After listing these *assertions*, we will explain how to construct the assertion that every row contains every integer from 1 to 9." 2/2

Comment: A *conjunction* like $p \land q$ **is** an assertion: "my name is Mauro and your name is Paul". There is nothing "ungrammatical" or "strange" in it. The same for a *disjunction*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I thought they were not assertions because I thought a conjunction was an operator like $+$. I interpreted the proposition$p \wedge q$ to be just an expression, like $2 + 3$, and  assertion "$(p \wedge q)$ is true" to be like $2+3=5$.  If all compound propositions are assertions, why is there a distinction between "proposition" and "assertion"? Is it the case that only atomic propositions can be propositions and not assertions?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Also, the sudoku example sounds very interesting but I think you might have a different book or edition, I could not this example on $33$ oe neighboring pages, and I could not find sudoku in the index

Comment: [7th edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0073383090/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1944687562&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0072899050&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=13YYPX6TGA3PE054WP9E), page 33.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the bulk of your question before your example:

The conditional statement asserts asserts that $q$ is true on the condition that $q$ holds, but the statement itself can be wrong. I can say that my statement $r$ is "if I never study ($p$), then I will always get 100% on my exams ($q$)". Then, when I refuse to study and fail the exam, $r$ itself is shown to be false.

In other words, $P \implies Q$ tries to assert something, but it is an unevaluated expression as much as $P \vee Q$ is.

I also used the Rosen textbook (7th edition, doesn't matter)

Comment: I understand that the statement itself can be evaluated as false, but  in the other question question, David C Ullrich seems to say that we cannot just add (is true) to any proposition. The books seems to say we can.

Comment: I don't see where Rosen says we can add "is true" arbitrarily? The conditional statement is a proposition because it can be evaluated to true or false given an interpretation. That is, I can say whether $p \implies q$ is true or false if you tell me what $p$ and $q$ are individually (that's the interpretation).

Comment: @Ovi: David is not, as far as I can see, saying that we cannot add "is true" to things. What he's saying is that there's no _need_ to do so (in ordinary informal mathematical prose), because it doesn't change the meaning being expressed.

Comment: What I actually said: _Of course when a person states something he's saying that that something is true. That's precisely why we don't need to add "is true" to that statement... _

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $p$ and $q$ are propositions, the compound proposition $p \vee q$ can be defined by its truth table.  This truth table has $4$ rows, and the truth value of $p \vee q$ will be $F$ only in the row where both $p$ and $q$ have truth value $F$.

Similarly, the conditional statement $p \implies q$ is defined to be the  proposition $(\sim p) \vee q$ whose truth value is $F$ only when $p$ is $T$ and $q$ is $F$.